# Eliminar paginación yii2

Tags: yii2, paginación

Buenas tengo una base de datos creada en un servidor y he creado modelos, controladores y vistas con gii de yii2. 
He dejado los controladores vacíos, es decir, como este por ejemplo:

```
 <?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class DietaController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Dieta';

}
```

Al hacer una petición GET a mi servidor todo funciona correctamente dado que me devuelve el xml con los registros de la tabla, pero cuando hay más de 20 registros solo me devuelve los 20 primeros y he creído que es la paginación, por lo que querría desactivarla dado que necesito todos.

El modelo es el siguiente:

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;


class Dieta extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'dieta';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['nid', 'aceite', 'aceiteTotal', 'racionesVerdura', 'piezasFruta', 'racionesCarneRoja', 'racionesMantequilla', 'bebidasAzucaradas', 'vino', 'racionesLegumbre', 'reposteria', 'carnePollo'], 'integer'],
            [['create_time'], 'safe'],
            [['nid'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Login::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['nid' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'idDieta' => 'Id Dieta',
            'nid' => 'Nid',
            'aceite' => 'Aceite',
            'aceiteTotal' => 'Aceite Total',
            'racionesVerdura' => 'Raciones Verdura',
            'piezasFruta' => 'Piezas Fruta',
            'racionesCarneRoja' => 'Raciones Carne Roja',
            'racionesMantequilla' => 'Raciones Mantequilla',
            'bebidasAzucaradas' => 'Bebidas Azucaradas',
            'vino' => 'Vino',
            'racionesLegumbre' => 'Raciones Legumbre',
            'reposteria' => 'Reposteria',
            'carnePollo' => 'Carne Pollo',
            'create_time' => 'Create Time',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getN()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Login::className(), ['id' => 'nid']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar como tiene construido el modelo? Adicionalmente veo que tiene extendido `DietaController` a `ActiveController` y no a `Controller`, esto es porque esta construyendo una Restful?

Comment: Buenas Ale, Sí tengo un servidor REST. A ver te explico que es lo que pretendo.  Tengo una aplicación móvil que hace uso del servicio y es la que llena la base de datos mediante peticiones POST y para algunas funcionalidades necesito hacer algún que otro GET. Adjunto el modelo a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parte de su controlador debería verse algo así:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

class DietaController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Dieta';

    public function actions()
    {

        $actions = parent::actions();

        $actions['index'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'prepareDataProvider' => function () {
                return new ActiveDataProvider([
                    'query' => \app\models\Dieta::find(),
                    'pagination' => false,
                ]);
            }
        ];

        return $actions;

    }
}
```

En el `ActiveDataProvider` se debe establecer la propiedad `pagination` en `false`, con esto se debería deshabilitar la paginación. Puede encontrar más detalle en la [documentación de Yii](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-indexaction#$prepareDataProvider-detail)

Comment: Buenas Ale, eso ya lo había probado antes pero me aparecía el siguiente error: **The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.** Muchas gracias por todo y disculpa que soy nuevo en php y yii y no lo comprendo muy bien

Comment: No te disculpes, para eso es este sitio. Edité la respuesta y agregue la propiedad `query`, intenta y verifica si funciona

Comment: Añadí lo que me indicaste y me aparece el siguiente error al recargar la página: `syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ']'`. Lo he puesto de la siguiente forma--> `'query' => $this->modelClass->findAll(),` por respuestas encontradas a otro error parecido pero no parece ser la solución ya que me da este error: `Call to a member function findAll() on a non-object`

Comment: Ese error se dio en el parámetro `query`, puse directamente que llame el método estático `findAll()`, con esto funcionando sería más fácil y haciendo un refactor del resto, edite la respuesta.

Comment: Buenas Ale, lo había probado como me lo indicas pero me aparecía el siguiente error: `Class 'app\controllers\app\models\Dieta' not found`

Comment: @Luis edité la respuesta, el problema fue en el namespace, ya no le debería dar el error

Comment: Hola Ale, soy un desastre, ahora me aparece lo siguiente y tampoco soy capaz de resolverlo: `Missing argument 1 for yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::findAll(), called in /var/www/basic/controllers/DietaController.php on line 22 and defined`

Comment: @Luis no hay mejor experiencia que esta, para no complicarlo y obtener el resultado que necesitas cambié el método `findAll()` por `find()->all()` que debería obtener todos los registros, inténtalo de nuevo

Comment: Me vuelve a aparecer el error del principio `The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.`

Comment: Ok, creo que esto sería como lo ultimo, sino te sirve por salud metal me tendría que armar un pequeño proyecto para revisar porque te da el error. Según esta [documentación](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/rest-resources#collections) bastaría con que `query` esté indicado así: `'query' => Dieta::find()` también lo edité en la respuesta

Comment: Ya funciona perfectamente, muchísimas gracias Ale, iré probando cosas nuevas ahora ya que es estable para ir aprendiendo poco a poco.

Comment: Excelente @Luis, no olvides marcar la respuesta que dí como correcta ... saludos